# How to pass local filename to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, classpath, applicationcontext

By "local filename" I mean that resource file is located in the same directory as class file. In the case below this is `JUnitRunner.class` file. Java's [`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) file can handle this if path does not start with `/`'

I can't figure out, how to do the same `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` constructor?

```
package springtests;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class JUnitRunner {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JUnitRunner.class);

    @Test
    public void test() throws URISyntaxException {

        String filename = "test01.xml";

        URL url = getClass().getResource(filename);


        File file = new File(url.toURI());
        log.info("File exists: {}", file.exists());

        try {
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(filename);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Can't load context", e);
        }

    }
}
```

the output follows

```
15:32:27,375 3    [main] INFO  springtests.JUnitRunner  - File exists: true
15:32:27,422 50   [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ee3aa7: startup date [Thu Nov 01 15:32:27 MSK 2012]; root of context hierarchy
15:32:27,475 103  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test01.xml]
15:32:27,477 105  [main] ERROR springtests.JUnitRunner  - Can't load context
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [test01.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test01.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)

...
```

**UPDATE**

XML file is located in the same folder as class file. It is visible from the fact that `getResource()` see it.

Comment: where you placed test01.xml? If you're using maven, can you put it, for example, in folder test/resources/test01.xml and try again your test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, your xml file in package `springtests` and correct creation of AppContext should be

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springtests/test01.xml");
```

Comment: this is absolute path, from the root; is it possible to use relative path, from the class location?

Comment: you can use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext() in that case.

Comment: How? Via Java resources API? not beautiful

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html you can set path relative to VM working directory or absolute path.

Answer (score 15):

I don't properly understand what is that you're asking, but have you tried:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:test01.xml");
```

That will search in all the classpath for `test01.xml`. You can read more about this in the Spring [resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/resources.html) documentation page.

Comment: I want to use specific place -- the same as class file.

Comment: @Augusto for _ClassPath_ XMLApplicationContext set "classpath*" part  isn't nessesary

Answer (score 0):

It might need to configure `DocumentBuilderFactory`. [Reference](http://flylib.com/books/en/1.104.1.61/1/)

Example :

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load an applicationcontext from a location relative to the current Class.

This is all you need to do to make it happen:

```
URL resourceUrl = JUnitRunner.class.getResource("test01.xml");
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(
    new UrlResource(resourceUrl));
```