# getting org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and got stuck with a small issue.

can you please tell me where I am making the mistake ?

Code:

```
public class GlobalClass 
{
    private  static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public static JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    public static void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jd) 
    {
        jdbcTemplate = jd;
    }
    public static  DataSource getDataSource() 
    {
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Autowired
    public static void setDataSource(DataSource datasrc) 
    {
        dataSource = datasrc;

    }

    public static void load()
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("**bean.xml");
        GlobalClass gs = (GlobalClass) ctx.getBean("Global");

    }
}
```

Bean

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.oracledriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:thin//localhost:1521/xe"/>
    <property name="username" value="system"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>


<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
</bean> 

<bean id="Global" class="com.example.springtransaction.GlobalClass">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean>
```

while running this program getting exception No bean named.

Exception in thread "main" **org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Global' available**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
    at com.example.springtransaction.GlobalClass.load(GlobalClass.java:40)
    at com.example.springtransaction.App.main(App.java:11)

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177288/how-to-pass-local-filename-to-classpathxmlapplicationcontext

Comment: where is your main method? why define the load method as static inside a bean and why it is getting a bean out of the application context? The bean you are looking to retrieve might not have been init yet. Do the "load method" content within the main method and share results

Comment: @dimitrisli yes I am calling this load method from main

Comment: finally resolve this issue. it was because of bean.xml file location. kept the fil e under src and now working but got some other errors